JWT Cookie Attributes Changing in Production (Azure App Service) Compared to Local Environment
Description
I am experiencing an issue where the properties of my JWT cookie (secure, sameSite) are changing when I deploy my application to Azure App Service. The same properties are correctly set in my local environment. I am seeking guidance on why this might be happening and how to ensure consistency between local and production environments.
Context:
Frontend: Deployed on Vercel
Backend: Deployed on Azure App Service
Issue: In production, the secure and sameSite properties of the JWT cookie appear to be altered, resulting in authentication failures. This does not occur in my local environment.
Issue: In production, the secure and sameSite properties of the JWT cookie appear to be altered, resulting in failures when making API calls to protected routes after login. This does not occur in my local environment.
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const generateToken = (res, userId) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "30d",
  });
  //sending back to frontend
  res.cookie("jwt", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "None",
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, //30 days
  });
};

export default generateToken;

Middleware and Configuration:  The following is the middleware and configuration setup for my Express application:
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import { app, server } from "./socket/socket.js";
import connectDB from "./config/db.js";
import { notFound, errorHandler } from "./middleware/errorMiddleware.js";
import authRoutes from "./routes/authRoutes.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/userRoutes.js";
import messagesRoutes from "./routes/messagesRoutes.js";

dotenv.config({ path: "config/.env" });

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.FRONTEND_URL,
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
  })
);

app.use("/api/users", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/messages", messagesRoutes);
app.use("/api/sidebarconversations", userRoutes);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("API is running...");
});

app.use(notFound);
app.use(errorHandler);

connectDB();

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
  console.log("Frontend connection coming from:", process.env.FRONTEND_URL);
});

Local Environment: In my local environment, the JWT cookie is set with the following properties:

secure: true

sameSite: "None"



Production Environment (Azure App Service):
In the production environment, the JWT cookie properties seem to change, causing failures when the frontend tries to make API calls to protected routes like /sidebarconversations after login:

secure: true
sameSite: "Strict" (unexpectedly changes from "None")


Question:
Why are the JWT cookie properties (secure, sameSite) being altered in the production environment when deployed to Azure App Service, and how can I ensure these properties remain consistent with my local environment settings?
Repository Link:
https://github.com/yashcrest/React-Node-Chat-App

secure attribute requires that the cookie is sent over HTTPS. If the local environment is not using HTTPS, then secure attribute will not apply, but in production (App Service), HTTPS is typically enforced.


I am seeking guidance on why this might be happening and how to ensure consistency between local and production environments.

Enable HTTPS in the Azure App Service by navigating to the web app -> TLS/SSL settings -> HTTPS Only and set it to On

The secure attribute requires that the cookie is sent over HTTPS. If the local environment is not using HTTPS, then secure attribute will not apply, but coming into production (App Service), HTTPS is typically involve.


If sameSite attribute set to None it requires the cookie to be secure. This also might impose differently in local env vs. production environments.
generateToken function:
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const generateToken = (res, userId) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "30d",
  });

  const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

  res.cookie("jwt", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: isProduction, // Use secure cookies in production
    sameSite: isProduction ? "None" : "Lax", // Adjust sameSite based on environment
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 30 days in milliseconds
  });
};

export default generateToken;

By this you can mitigate issues with cookie properties being altered in production.
HTTPS setup in Local Development:

Here is set-up with HTTPS in the local environment using self-signed certificates.

Use tool like OpenSSL to generate a self-signed certificate and key


const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certs', 'key.pem')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'certs', 'cert.pem'))
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at https://localhost:${port}`);
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello HTTPS!');
});

After deployment:



I found what the issue was, apparently when you deploy from VS code, it does not continuously deploy every commit from your repo to AZ app service. Once I connected it again from AZ portal it got fixed. I ended up writing an article about different ways to deploy your project to AZ app service as well :).
https://medium.com/@yashcrest/learning-experience-from-hosting-api-in-azure-app-service-9341c5b8005f
